# snapsvg to png with Custom font

Tags: javascript, png, snap.svg

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="snap.svg-min.js"></script> <style> @font-face { font-family: Avenir; src: url("/AvenirNextCondensed-DemiBold.otf") format("opentype"); } </style> <script> window.onload = function(){ //Start with a simple raphaelJs drawing var s = Snap('#svg', 200,200); var r = s.rect(4,4,192,192,100,100).attr({ stroke: '#1A171B', 'strokeWidth': 4, fill: 'FFDD00', 'opacity': 1.0 }); var t1 = s.text((200/2),(200/2)+20, "150"); t1.attr({ 'font-size': 110, 'font-family': 'Avenir', fill:'#3D3C3F', 'text-anchor':'middle' }); var t2 = s.text((200/2),(200/2)+75, "ex"); t2.attr({ 'font-size': 80, 'font-family': 'Avenir', fill:'#3D3C3F', 'text-anchor':'middle' }); document.getElementById('img').src = s.toDataURL(); } </script> <svg id="svg"></svg> <img id="img"></img>
```

Hello,

The "svg" is drawing with the correct font-family, but the "img" don't.
See result here : http://pictos.kagwalmina.fr/index3.html

Is my code who is wrong or it's a bug ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe the custom font dosen't work, can you try with a standard font?

Comment: explain your question more. you are having issue in fonts during "svg to png" conversion?

Comment: Hello. Yes, i have the issue during the "svg to png" conversion.

Comment: @LeonardoBuscemi : Yes, if i try with standard font, the svg to png conversion works well (i try with Arial). My question is about an external font with a ttf, otf or svg font file.

Answer (score 0):

To make custom font works, make sure you add them inside your "svg" using "defs" tags

example:

```
 <defs>
    <font-face font-family="Knewave">
       <font-face-src>
         <font-face-uri link:href="path_to_font/css/fonts/Knewave-Regular.ttf">
         </font-face-uri>
       </font-face-src>
   </font-face>   
</defs>
```

And now when you convert your SVG to Image, it should show correct font for that text